# How to modify preg_replace_callback pattern to match <p> element with or without attributes?

Tags: php, regex

How can I change the pattern so that it matches p tags with attributes or without? Currently, it only matches on p tags without attributes.

```
$replaced_content = preg_replace_callback('#(<p>.*?</p>)#', 'p_callback', $content);
```

Example content #1:

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0;">
    <a href="test.jpg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
        <img style="float: left; margin: 10px; max-width: 25%;" title="test" src="test.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
    <p>
        <a href="test" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
            <img title="PDF file" src="test.png" alt="PDF file" /> 
            <span style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">Test ...</span>
        </a>
        <span>test <strong>test</strong> test? test, test, i.e., </span>
        <a href="test.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> ... Get Content Here</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Example content #2

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0;">
    <a href="test.jpg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
        <img style="float: left; margin: 10px; max-width: 25%;" title="test" src="test.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
    <p style="margin:10px; float:left">
        <a href="test" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
            <img title="PDF file" src="test.png" alt="PDF file" /> 
            <span style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">Test ...</span>
        </a>
        <span>test <strong>test</strong> test? test, test, i.e., </span>
        <a href="test.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> ... Get Content Here</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [s (PCRE_DOTALL)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier:

*Edited according to Dor Shemer's comment*

```
$replaced_content = preg_replace_callback('#(<p[\s>].*?</p>)#s', 'p_callback', $content
```

Comment: Although this might seem scary, I think it's the best solution unless you want to start doing mental look-arounds. +1

Comment: I'd change to `<p[\s>].*?</p>` just to make sure it won't start in `<pre>` tags or something else that starts with p